# How does terraform handle Infrastructure autoscaling

Tags: terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I understand that terraform works using statefile, But I would like to understand how can we handle terraform in case of scaled up/scaled down instances.
Example:
I have an Instance group with minimum 1 and maximum 3 instances. At the time of creation I have one instance, It scaled up to 2 instances. Now when I am trying to run "terraform apply" terraform is trying to scale down my Instance group to 1.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How have you defined your instance group? It would help if you edited your question to show your code and then explain what is happening out of band to cause it to scale out and then show the plan output that wants to scale it back down.

Comment: If you defined in your terraform code some autoscaling group with a desired count value when you apply the changes terraform will be to overwrite the resource with the values defined in your local code.

Comment: As @ydaetskcoR mentioned, It would be helpful to understand your set up and seek for a solution to the issue if you share your terraform code. I suggest you to see the example usage of the MIG autoscaler in terraform in the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_autoscaler).

Answer (score -1):

In **Documentation** https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group they state :

`the aws_autoscaling_group resource must be configured to ignore changes to the load_balancers and target_group_arns arguments within a lifecycle configuration block.`

use `ignore_changes` to ignore Autoscaling changes, an example:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  # ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
     load_balancers,
     target_group_arns
    ]
  }
}
```

test that, if not working as expected, add `min` and `max` to ignore changes

Comment: They're using GCP, not AWS.

Comment: Oh, did not notice the tags, thank you. anyway, I hope this can help someone searching for ASG